# How to build a graph with networkx from twitter data

Tags: python, twitter, networkx

So I'm a beginner but I want to visualise the mentions of a user using networkx in Python. I already collected all of the tweets I want to look at using the Twitter API and put them into a data frame. 
The data frame has all sorts of data about the tweets but I am most interested in the user (5 users in the DF) and who was mentioned in the tweet of the user.

```
+-------+---------------------+
|user   |mentioned_user       |
+-------+---------------------+
|user1  |jack,peter,anne      |
|user2  |sophie               |
|user2  |anne,user1           |
+-------+---------------------+
```

I realize I can extract the data I need using from_pandas_edgelist like so:

```
test = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    df,
    source='user',
    target='mentioned_user',
    edge_attr=True,
    create_using=nx.DiGraph()
)
```

But what do I do next? I would like to have a plot for each user where the user and mentioned_user are nodes.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your code you will create nodes from strings in `'user'` column to strings in `'mentioned_user'` column as-is, without splitting them to different users. So you should split `'mentioned_user'` column and iterate through the dataframe manually:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user':['user1','user2','user2'],
    'mentioned_user':['jack,peter,anne','sophie','anne,user1']
})
df['splitted_users'] = df['mentioned_user'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))

G = nx.DiGraph()
for r in df.iterrows():
    for user in r[1]['splitted_users']:
        G.add_edge(r[1]['user'], user)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

will draw you:

[image]

Comment: Incredible, thank you so much! Just one more question: do you know if I can pass the parameters for e.g. node size and number of nodes to display directly in nx.draw()? The problem is, I have just five users but several thousand mentioned users, so currently the plot is not readable.

Comment: Of course. If you can draw not every node, create a subgraph and visualize it. You can change node size with `node_size` parameter. You can read more about it here: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx